# Convert integer to ListItem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to convert an integer to a ListItem.

My code is as below.

```
 var returnList = from p in dataList
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = p.ID,
                      URL = Helper.GetDetailPageUrl((SPListItem)p.ID)
                  };
```

In helper file:

```
public static string GetDetailPageUrl(SPListItem currentItem)
{
     .....................
}
```

Comment: What is the type of p? Is not it splistitem itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the ID of the listitem - sharepoint exclusively does that.

Also, you can't have item's ID before it is saved to sharepoint